# Making clear I am doing just the first tasks

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

In a message I sent, I wrote:

> I am preparing my room to be painted, which means I am moving furniture out of the room, and cleaning the walls from the mold. There isn't nothing much I need to do.

Leaving out the last sentence, which I would have thought could suggest I was not the person painting my room, would not *to be painted* suggest painting my room was not a task for me?

I think that *I am preparing my room to paint it* would imply that painting my room was my task.

Is there another sentence I could have used to make clear I was doing the preparatory tasks to allow another person to paint my room without explicitly saying *another person will paint my room*?

Comment: "to be painted" just says that the painting will be in the future, not who is doing it. Having "I" as the subject of the sentence doesn't help with your intended meaning. Saying something like "My room will be painted soon so I am preparing it..." would be better.

Comment: There are also other grammar issues with your message, but I guess that is off-topic...

Comment: "There isn't nothing much I need to do" is not grammatically correct, by the way, because it uses a double negative.  I think you mean "There **is** nothing much I need to do."

Comment: @SteveES If you want to address issues other than the specific one in the question when you write an answer, I think that would be great. More information and more explanation is a good thing, especially when you think of the folks that will look at the answers in the future. The question that led them here might not be exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have phrased:

> I am preparing my room to be painted

Does not imply anything about who will do the painting, it is left ambiguous. If anything, having "I" as the subject might imply that **you** are the one who will do the painting.

If you change the subject of the first clause to be **my room** and make a second clause about **your actions**, this gives a much stronger implication that you are **not** the one who will be doing the painting. E.g.

> My room will be painted soon, so I am preparing it by moving furniture out and cleaning the walls.

---

There are a couple of other grammatical problems with your message:

It should be "**cleaning mold from the walls**", not "cleaning the walls from the mold". The walls are a permanent object and you are taking the mold away from the surface of it, therefore the mold is on the walls, not vice versa.

**"isn't nothing much"** is a [double-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative), so means the opposite of what you want it to mean. While it is common (in speech) in certain dialects, it is considered bad grammar and so should generally be avoided. To give your intended meaning, you could use either:

> is nothing much

or

> isn't anything much

either would be fine, but the former is perhaps preferable.